Ruby koan: why I the test case result different with irb result?
I follow ruby koan https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/blob/master/src/about_symbols.rb#L26-L29
My irb
irb(main):006> symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
=> false
irb(main):007> symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
=>
["!",
...
irb(main):008> symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
=> false
irb(main):009>


My code (pass test case)
def test_method_names_become_symbols
  symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
  assert_equal true, symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
end


Why in source code, it is not
assert_equal false, symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")


Your code checks for the existence of the :test_method_names_become_symbols symbol. If it returns false in irb, it's because the :test_method_names_become_symbols symbol isn't defined:
symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
#=> false

If you define it beforehand, it'll return true:
:test_method_names_become_symbols

symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
#=> true

Your code in irb behaves different from your test because you are skipping the method definition. Defining a method also creates a corresponding symbol, it's even returned as the result of the method definition:
def test_method_names_become_symbols
end
#=> :test_method_names_become_symbols

symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
#=> true

And because the symbol is created right at the beginning of the method definition, running the code within the method also works:
def test_method_names_become_symbols
  symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
  symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
end

test_method_names_become_symbols
#=> true

